# Reinstate Known Traveller Number

Tags: usa

My son's KTN was revoked due to a false identification on a warrant. He was cleared by the courts. How does he get his KTN reinstated?

Comment: Close voters: what's unclear about this?

Comment: Was it Nexus, Global Entry, or what? Did he get a letter when it was revoked, and is there contact information in that letter? Is he a US citizen?

Answer (score 2):

You can find out how to begin the appeal process at [Trusted Traveler application denied](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1150/~/trusted-traveler-application-denied).

Comment: Seriously?  A Downvote for the link to appeal process?  Totally unwarranted and clear evidence of 100% wrong and misleading Downvotes.  Very unhelpful to the community.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect that the downvote is a reaction to the fact that this answer is little better than a link-only answer.  A good answer should at least summarize the relevant information from its cited sources.